# How to check elements in std::unique_ptr<int[]>?

Tags: c++, c++11, googlemock

I have a function that returns a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` and I would like check in a unit test that it returns the correct elements. It looks like code like the following doesn't work:

```
std::vector<int> foo = {1, 2, 3};
std::unique_ptr<int[]> bar = my_func();
EXPECT_THAT(bar, ElementsAreArray(foo))
```

I've also tried replacing `bar` with `bar.get()` in the assert, but I'm still getting strange type errors.

Comment: *bar ?..........

Comment: Please expand upon "doesn't work". What happened, and what were you expecting? You mention type errors -- please copy the error message into your question. Those messages are intended to tell you what you did wrong; learning to understand them will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

`bar.get()` will return a raw (non-owning) pointer to same memory that `unique_ptr` is referring to. What you want, is to dereference the `unique_ptr` to return the underlying integer array.

Even so, your `EXPECT_THAT` will not succeed, as it will try to equate its arguments with the `operator==`, this won't be available for `int[]` and `vector<int>` unless you define it. Alternatively, you could place the `EXPECT_THAT` line in a loop and iterate through the two containers.